# Django Initial Usage for getting latest id to print to form

Tags: django

I wanna make patient register form and i want each new patient start with initial number. So this is my form. I did these views.py codes but, on the screen nothing. How can i fix this. And then my real goal is start patient register with a default=0 id and then each new patient id must be +1 extra. How can i do this.
Thanks for help.

[image]

Here are my codes.

Models.py

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("F", "Female"),
        ("O", "Other")
    )
    """ aadhaarId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True ) """
    aadhaarId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=6, help_text= "12 digit aadhar no" )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(max_length=8, help_text="YYYY-MM-DD")
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    
    # Patients  will be sorted using this field
    last_updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "patient"
        verbose_name_plural = "patients"
        ordering = ["-last_updated_on"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '-' + self.aadhaarId
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def patientCreate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        intaial_data = {
        'aadhaarId': '999088'}
        
        
        form = PatientForm(request.POST, initial=intaial_data)
        id = request.POST['aadhaarId']
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'New Patient is successfully added.!')
                model = form.instance
                return redirect('/patient-detail/{}'.format(id))
            except:
                messages.error(request, 'failed to add patient')
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
    return render(
        request, 'patient_records/patient-create.html', {'form': form}
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which gives count of the patients in the table and use it as the reference to generate new Id

**Cons :**

sql databases uses incremental approch so. If a table has 10 users with id's 0 to 9 and one user of id 4 left then the new user won't occupy the space of 4 but instead a new id is created with id 10  so for this scenario you will get duplicate id's to over come this you can follow the below approch.

Though you can over come this issue with the help of

> You can retrieve the most recent automatically generated AUTO_INCREMENT value with the LAST_INSERT_ID() SQL function or the mysql_insert_id() C API function. These functions are connection-specific, so their return values are not affected by another connection which is also performing inserts.Refer [Get Last Used Id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)